# Youtube API to get most viewed video for a day

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

- Is there a way to get the most viewed video on youtube for a particular day?
- Is there any **API** available for it?
- Is there some source which gives you the video ?

Answer (score 14):

Yeah they don't have stats on a particular day but they do have a running viewCount. So you can use the API info at

```
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list
```

to make something like

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&order=viewCount&publishedAfter=2014-10-29T00%3A00%3A00Z&publishedBefore=2014-10-31T00%3A00%3A00Z&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Maybe that will help?