# How to get most popular videos on a daily basis for a date range using YouTube API?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I understand there is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26648543/youtube-api-to-get-most-viewed-video-for-a-day) asked 7 years ago.
I wonder if there is any changes in the YouTube API.

Basically, I want to get the video statistics from YouTube using the API below on a `GET` request:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=id,statistics,snippet{page_token}chart=mostPopular&regionCode={country_code}&maxResults=50&key={api_key}`.

However, I want to get:

- The most popular (first 200 for example) videos on a daily basis for a specific date range

I have checked the YouTube API page [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics%22%5D%2C%22chart%22%3A%22mostPopular%22%2C%22regionCode%22%3A%22US%22%7D), but there is no parameter for me to get the most popular videos statistics from previous date range.

Any advise how to do so? Is it possible?

Comment: How do you define most popular?

Comment: @DaImTo, most popular is defined as the most number of views

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there has been any changes to the YouTube API in years.  Personally i would sort by rating and not view count but I think that depends on what you count as popularity.

```
curl \
  'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=200&order=rating&publishedAfter=2021-03-06T00%3A00%3A01Z&publishedBefore=2021-03-06T23%3A59%3A01Z&fields=*&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

If you want previous date range you just need to build up a different call with different dates.

You can test it in the [try me](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22snippet%22%5D%2C%22maxResults%22%3A200%2C%22order%22%3A%22rating%22%2C%22publishedAfter%22%3A%222021-03-06T00%3A00%3A01Z%22%2C%22publishedBefore%22%3A%222021-03-06T23%3A59%3A01Z%22%2C%22fields%22%3A%22*%22%7D)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, `publishedAfter` & `publishedBefore` are not suitable for me. For example, a video published few years ago might be the most popular today.

Comment: Again this is how you read your question.   Most popular videos posted on a date.   Your options are very limited with this api.